# Is there any legal way to create IMAP folder with hierarchy separator character in the name?

Tags: imap

In the IMAP protocol there is a folder hierarchy character. If you try to create folder with such character in the name, mailserver will create two folders. For example, if a delimiter character is "/", then command `CREATE "aaa/bbb"` will create two folders `aaa` and `bbb` in folder `aaa`.

Is it possible to create *single* folder with delimiter character inside? For example, the single folder with the name `aaa/bbb`, without `aaa` and `bbb` in `aaa` folder.

Comment: Even if you could, it will probably cause something to break somewhere.  I'd avoid even trying, if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try UTF7 encoding:

```
CREATE "one&AC8-two"
```

But RFC says:

> If the server's hierarchy separator
>   character appears elsewhere in the
>   name, the server SHOULD create any
>   superior hierarchical names that are
>   needed for the CREATE command to be
>   successfully completed.  In other
>   words, an attempt to create
>   "foo/bar/zap" on a server in which "/"
>   is the hierarchy separator character
>   SHOULD create foo/ and foo/bar/ if
>   they do not already exist."

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html

Comment: Well, it looks like a hack than a feature. Could break some client applications.

Comment: All clients should support UTF7 encoding, so may opinion is it should not cause problems. Have you checked if it works with your server/client?

Comment: yep, it's working for thunderbird and kmail, checked some server, also ok

Answer (score 6):

@Pawel - tried you trick, didn't work with dovecot.  Resorted to reading the RFC.

The correct way, is to create a folder with trailing /

Here's an example (taken direct from a manual IMAP session):

```
[root@mailer-daemon ~]# telnet localhost imap
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to mailer-daemon.co (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK Dovecot ready.
A1 LOGIN user password
A1 OK Logged in.
A1 LIST "" *
* LIST (\NoInferiors \UnMarked) "/" "Drafts"
* LIST (\NoInferiors \UnMarked) "/" "Deleted Messages"
* LIST (\NoInferiors \UnMarked) "/" "INBOX"
A1 OK List completed.
A1 CREATE test/
A1 OK Create completed.
A1 CREATE test/case
A1 OK Create completed.
A1 LIST "" test*
* LIST (\Noselect \HasChildren) "/" "test"
* LIST (\NoInferiors \UnMarked) "/" "test/case"
A1 OK List completed.
```

And here's the RFC saying the same thing

```
  If the mailbox name is suffixed with the server's hierarchy
  separator character (as returned from the server by a LIST
  command), this is a declaration that the client intends to create
  mailbox names under this name in the hierarchy.  Server
  implementations that do not require this declaration MUST ignore
  the declaration.  In any case, the name created is without the
  trailing hierarchy delimiter.

  If the server's hierarchy separator character appears elsewhere in
  the name, the server SHOULD create any superior hierarchical names
  that are needed for the CREATE command to be successfully
  completed.  In other words, an attempt to create "foo/bar/zap" on
  a server in which "/" is the hierarchy separator character SHOULD
  create foo/ and foo/bar/ if they do not already exist.

  If a new mailbox is created with the same name as a mailbox which
  was deleted, its unique identifiers MUST be greater than any
  unique identifiers used in the previous incarnation of the mailbox
  UNLESS the new incarnation has a different unique identifier
  validity value.  See the description of the UID command for more
  detail.
```

I think this is the money shot:

```
Example:   C: A003 CREATE owatagusiam/
           S: A003 OK CREATE completed
           C: A004 CREATE owatagusiam/blurdybloop
           S: A004 OK CREATE completed

    Note: The interpretation of this example depends on whether
    "/" was returned as the hierarchy separator from LIST.  If
    "/" is the hierarchy separator, a new level of hierarchy
    named "owatagusiam" with a member called "blurdybloop" is
    created.  Otherwise, two mailboxes at the same hierarchy
    level are created.
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no, there is no way officially allowed by the protocol.

The accepted answer violates the protocol:

> In modified UTF-7, printable US-ASCII characters, except for "&", represent themselves; that is, characters with octet values 0x20-0x25 and 0x27-0x7e. […] Modified BASE64 MUST NOT be used to represent any printing US-ASCII character which can represent itself.
>
> — [5.1.3.  Mailbox International Naming Convention](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3)

The hack only works because most servers aren't strict about the above rule.

Comment: RTFRTC: 2) UTF-7's encoding is BASE64 which uses the "/" character; this conflicts with the use of "/" as a popular hierarchy delimiter. 4) Usually, a character (determined by the server implementation) is reserved to delimit levels of hierarchy. If it is desired to export hierarchical mailbox names, mailbox names MUST be left-to-right hierarchical using a single character to separate levels of hierarchy.  The same hierarchy separator character is used for all levels of hierarchy within a single name.